# Floating point exception (Core dumped) during installing a .run file

Tags: linux, fedora

I'm trying to install .run file in Fedora and I get this exception.
This is what I'm trying to do:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 user user 159472511 Mar 24 10:00 xampp.run
[root@localhost Programs]# ./xampp.run 
Floating point exception (core dumped)
[root@localhost Programs]#
```

Comment: did you change the permession for xampp.run?  "chmod 755 xampp.run"

Comment: This is a general Error and we cannot say exactly what happened. Try to find the log of coredump in the operating system, and add information to the post, that said what exactly this Error is related to

Comment: Example : `$ chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.4.3-0-installer.run`. ... `# ./xampp-linux-x64-7.4.3-0-installer.run` → OK, the GUI opens.

Comment: Hi.
yes I did change the permission but i get the same

Comment: @SiGNoR . 
I'm new in linux so what is mean **"find the log of coredump in the operating system, and add information to the post"**